# Configurable product in Magento 1.9, breaks attributes to individual products

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product

When i create a configurable product with size, the product breaks into individual products like the image given

The number next to the name is the size number

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured the simple products to be also visible in catalog. Make them not visible. Only the configurable has to be visible.